# How to clear invalid transactions from one's wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallet, bitcoin-core, doublespend

I've recently been testing double-spend attacks against myself using a couple wallets, and the standard client does not appear to clear conflicting transactions from its transaction list, even if the other ones have already become a part of a block. How do I get rid of invalid transactions from my wallet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to recover from an accidental double-spend?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3654/what-is-the-best-way-to-recover-from-an-accidental-double-spend)

Comment: For future reference, use a throwaway wallet for this type of activity.

Comment: @StephenGornick I did, but I'd like to recover any remaining balance from those addresses and the standard client tends to calculate its balance based on all transaction it sees, even the invalid ones, so I'm not sure how many Bitcoins I have left.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered before for someone to clear a too low fee transaction that wasn't accepted by the network. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/2415/1461